# How to dectect windows shutdown or restart time using Java?

Tags: java, uptime

how to view windows shutdown and restart time using java can anyone help
i have code for startup windows

```
Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c systeminfo | find \"System Boot Time:\"");
```

Comment: why dont you better call the UpTime in the system... from there you can induce the info you need

Comment: checkout this, http://serverfault.com/questions/159612/windows-server-last-reboot-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that you are trying to execute is correct.

You will need to wait or the process to complete and return the output. Use the `waitFor()` method of the `Process` object before getting the InputStream from it.

This sample code might get you started:

```
    Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c systeminfo | find \"System Boot Time:\"");
    uptimeProc.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Boot Time : " + line);
```

> **Update**

Try these two pieces of code for finding the boot time and shutdown time in windows. These are determined based on the events generated in the Windows Event Manager. Boot up event ID is 6005 and that of Shutdown is 1074.

Sources:

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=6005&EvtSrc=EventLog&LCID=1033

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1074&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033

Boot time:

```
    Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell -Command \"get-eventlog System | where-object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | sort -desc TimeGenerated\"");
    uptimeProc.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Shutdown time:

```
    Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell -Command \"get-eventlog System | where-object {$_.EventID -eq '1074'} | sort -desc TimeGenerated\"");
    uptimeProc.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

You will need to perform some amount of extraction. But this should hopefully put you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got you anacron but i need code for shutdown or restart time

Comment: Is there any dos command to identify last shutdown and restart time???

Comment: @AliHassanChughtai I've updated my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very much. I became hopeless but at last one more Help

Comment: I am getting  output in this way

Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message                                           
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------                                           
  187957 Nov 25 10:01  Information Microsoft-Windows...          107 The description for Event ID '107' in Source 'M...

so how can i only get time from it? plz one last Help :)

Comment: You will have to do some amount of filtering and sorting to find the latest event for an event ID. I think the command I gave already sorts the events by time stamp in descending order. So latest event is on top. You will have to extract that line and extract the time of start up and shut down.